# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} - \frac{3}{4k^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What ways would you propose for the limit below?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} - \frac{3}{4k^2}\right)$$

Thanks in advance for your suggestions, hints!

Sis.

Comment: Boy, I went to the wrong high school!

Comment: My next question on the Riemann Hypothesis will be called "elementary school question".

Comment: Where is this high school?

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: I see.

Comment: I feel stupid now. I only got to this stuff at university level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}-\frac{3}{4k^2} =n(H_{2n}^{(2)}-H_{n}^{(2)})=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{n}{(j+n)^2}\to\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} =\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This is incorrect. The limit indeed converges, but not to the limit you stated.

Comment: Could you tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: I think he is right.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: I think you're almost correct. But notice that you have $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx=1/2$. So, thanks!

Comment: Ah, thanks. I made one of those stupid mistakes that I always make.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: (+1) for your work.

Comment: @Chis's sister and pals Where do you get these questions?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: I have them from my brother.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a high school level answer:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{(2k-1)^2}-\frac3{4k^2}\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{(2k-1)^2}+\frac1{(2k)^2}-\frac1{k^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using partial fractions and summing the telescoping series, we get
$$
\hspace{-1cm}
\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{2n+2}
=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{k(k+1)}
\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}
\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{k(k-1)}
=\frac1n-\frac1{2n}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) and $(2)$ yield
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}=\frac12\tag{3}
$$

Comment: Oh, this is a candidate for the penultimate high school year since you used no integral. Just awesome! (+1) Actually, excepting the limit part, it could also be a good problem for the middle school.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: I don't usually post two answers to the same question, but the prerequisite level of these answers was so disparate, that I felt I should.

Comment: I have no problem with that. For me the answers are important! :-)

Comment: Very nice!${}{}$

Comment: (+1) The easier, the better.

Answer (score 17):

OK, it turns out that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} - \frac{3}{4k^2}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(k+n)^2}$$

This may be shown by observing that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{2 n-1} \frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{1}{2^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$$

The desired limit may then be rewritten as

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(1 + (k/n))^2}$$

which you may recognize as a Riemann sum, equal to

$$\int_0^1 dx \: \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: nice work and well shown. (+1)

Comment: This is the way I wanted to go, but I went with the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula as an alternative :-) (+1)

Comment: Nice to see it done different ways.

Comment: I have added yet another way :-)

Comment: You're an animal, @robjohn!

Answer (score 10):

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula),
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{(2k-1)^2}-\frac3{4k^2}\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{(2k-1)^2}+\frac1{(2k)^2}-\frac1{k^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\\
&=\left(C-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)-\left(C-\frac1n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{(2k-1)^2}-\frac3{4k^2}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Another good shot with  Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula. Thanks John! (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: I am writing up a high school level answer now.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{n\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\fermi\pars{k}}:\ {\large ?}.
     \qquad\fermi\pars{k} \equiv {1 \over \pars{2k -1}^{2}} - {3 \over 4k^{2}}}$

> Note that $\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{k} = 0}$ because
>   $$
> \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{k}
> =\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2k - 1}^{2}}
> -\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{3 \over 4k^{2}}
> =\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}
> -\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2k}^{2}}}
> -\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{3 \over 4k^{2}}
> $$

With [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/05/08/stolz-cesaro-theorem/):
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
n\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \fermi\pars{k}}}=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}%
\fermi\pars{k} \over 1/n}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1}\fermi\pars{k} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\fermi\pars{k}
\over 1/\pars{n + 1} - 1/n}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{-n\pars{n + 1}\fermi\pars{n + 1}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\braces{n\pars{n + 1}
\bracks{{3 \over 4\pars{n + 1}^{2}} - {1 \over 4\pars{n + 1}^{2}}}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{n \over n + 1}=\color{#66f}{\Large\half}
\end{align}

Comment: Good job there! (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssis Thanks. You are always posting interesting questions.